# Fetching methods from BroadcastReceiver to update UI

Tags: java, android, static, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to update the UI according to change of a variable in `BroadcastReceiver`. Thus, I need to call a method (to get the variable I mentioned) of a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver` in `MainActivity` depending on but I cannot get the true return value in any way.

The class which extends `BroadcastReceiver` is this:

```
public class ProviderChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static boolean isProviderActive;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            Log.v("-> ", "GPS + NETWORK");
            isProviderActive = true;
        }

        else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            Log.v("-> ", "GPS");
            isProviderActive = true;
        }

        else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) && !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Log.v("-> ", "NETWORK");
            isProviderActive = true;
        }

        else
        {
            Log.v("-> ", "DISCONNECT");
            isProviderActive = false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isProviderActive(){
        return isProviderActive;
    }
}
```

I need to get true value of `isProviderActive` to use in this part of `MainActivity`:

```
...
private class ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI extends ProviderChangeReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        MapsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("-A", ""+ isProviderActive());
                if (isProviderActive())
                    originButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    originButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know that indicating `isProviderActive` as static is not a good approach but I just want to observe its changes. As you guess, I got nonsensical return values all the time. To values of `boolean isProviderActive` without problem, what do you advise?

Edit: My temporary solution to update UI according to changes in `BroadcastReceiver`.

Forget about creating a separate class for `ProviderChangeReceiver`. Instead of the code segment above, following segment should be added in `MainActivity`. Also, it goes without saying that there is the initialization of `ProviderChangeReceiver` in `onCreate()`.

```
...
private class ProviderChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        MapsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("COUNT: ", "" + count++);
                if (isLocationProviderActive()) {
                    originButton.getBackground().setAlpha(220);
                    originButton.setEnabled(true);
                    //marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                    originButton.getBackground().setAlpha(77);
                    originButton.setEnabled(false);
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private boolean isLocationProviderActive(){
    if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Of course then register the receiver in `onCreate()` as well:

```
registerReceiver(pcr, new IntentFilter("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that every time `isProvidrActive` changed the whole activity got regenerated is because I sent the intent using `context.startActivity(i)` but rather this time we send the intent using `contect.sendBroadcast(i)` to the `ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI` inner class which update only desired part of the UI. So below is the new code.

```
private static boolean isProviderActive;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v("-> ", "GPS + NETWORK");
        isProviderActive = true;
    }

    else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v("-> ", "GPS");
        isProviderActive = true;
    }

    else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) && !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v("-> ", "NETWORK");
        isProviderActive = true;
    }

    else
    {
        Log.v("-> ", "DISCONNECT");
        isProviderActive = false;
    }

    //Send value of isProviderActive to ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI.class);
    i.putExtra("isProvidrActv", isProviderActive);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

---

Edit your manifest file to enable the inner class `ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI` to listen for broadcast sent by our `broadcastReciever`, add the following entry to manifest

```
<receiver  android:name="<package-name>.MainActivity$ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

the $ sign indicates inner class. No need to add `intent-filters` unless required.

And in your `ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI` class in the `onReceive()` method get the value of `isProviderActive`

```
...
//changed the identifiers from private to public static and the class extends //BroadcastReceiver
public static class ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //Empty constructor to prevent exception can't instantiate no empty constructor
    public ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI(){

    }

    //Removed the final keyword from handler
    private Handler handler; // Handler used to execute code on the UI thread

    public ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        boolean isProvidrActv = intent.getBooleanExtra("isProvidrActv", false);
        //mapsActivity is a global static object of the class MapsActivity<br/>
        //instantiate it the onCreate() method of mainactivity for ex:<br/>
/*public class MapsActivity extends Activity{<br/>
         static MapsActivity mapsActivity;

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate){
        ma  = new MapsActivity();
        }*/
        mapsActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isProvidrActv)
                    originButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    originButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. Is getBooleanExtra() in the correct method? I cannot get the value of isProviderActive continuosly still, it goes "false" for once and then never changes.

Comment: No, it is an inner class of the main class. I just copied that part to keep short the post. I added the code segment in onResume() of main one.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake that in the onResume() method i wrote getBooleanExtra("isProviderActive", false) instead of getBooleanExtra("isProvidrActv", false) the reason that you wre continously getting false was that the string label of the boolean which is send through intent should be same as that of label being used to getBooleanExtra in onResume().Since no boolean with label "isProviderActive" was being sent via intent by ProviderChangeReceiver  that is why you were getting a default value false by the getBooleanExtra() method. Continued..

Comment: In short in the  in OnResume change the method getBooleanExtra(""isProviderActive", false) to getBooleanExtra(""isProvidrActv", false).hope this helps.Waiting for your reply

Comment: I already corrected that mistake, it was obvious. That was not the cause of the problem unfortunately.

Comment: did you try getBooleanExtra() in the onRecieve() of ProviderChangeReciever_updateUI. If not I updated the code above

Comment: Still not working. I can change UI dynamically and properly now but the solution is not so great. I edited it on the question. Basically, I moved ProviderChangeReceiver class in MainActivity and did the all work there. Too higgledy-piggledy approach but it works. I am open for suggestions to improve the solution still. Getting value from intent seems much more judicious.

Comment: I think i get it now, you are trying to say that whenever the value of boolean isProviderActive changes the broadcastreciver sholud send that value to inner class ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI and then accordingly the visibility of originButton should be set.If that,s the case then we could send a broadcast intent to the inner class ProviderChangeReceiver_updateUI, which will be recieved by its onRecieve() method. I would be posting that code .Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Exactly. It is my fault. I could not explain the situation clearly.

Comment: I corrected your approach in my implementation. Your structure works but this time it regenerates entire UI (included the map) from scratch when the provider is changed. Actually, I am happy with my solution but it is messy a little bit and I want to find out why your suggestion is not functioning as it should be. Thank you though. That is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me the correction you implemented,  it will be really helpful for me to know what was wrong in my approach
Thanks again

Comment: I am not sure about the place of getBooleanExtra() still. As I said, this approach can properly change the visibility of the button but it also tangles up other functions which are not changed in run(). Except these, the problem is about a part (not included in explanation of the question) of my implementation.

Comment: I have written another piece of code and this one recieves the getBooleanExtra() in the onReceive of inner class method.
I will be posting an updated solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice way to handle something like this is with an eventbus.

Take a look at Squares [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library.

In your broadcast receiver you would publish the change event and then in your activity you would subscribe to the event and update the ui.

Based on the context of your question,  I think you would be able to avoid the broadcast receiver entirely, since I suspect you have something watching your provider and then broadcasting the event.

### Update: (based on comments)

I think the way this would work would be something like this

In the code that detects the change in location provider:

```
if (bothProvidersAreStopped()) {
   bus.publish(new BothProvidersStoppedEvent());
} else if (onlyNetworkProviderIsStopped() {
   bus.publish(new NetworkProviderStoppedEvent());
} else if (onlyGpsProviderIsStopped() {
   bus.publish(new GpsProviderStoppedEvent());
}
```

in your activity

```
@Subscribe public void onBothProvidersStopped(BothProvidersStopped event) {
    // handle case were both providers just stopped
}

@Subscribe public void onNetworkProvidersStopped(BothProvidersStopped event) {
    // handle case were network provider just stopped
}

@Subscribe public void onGpsProvidersStopped(BothProvidersStopped event) {
    // handle case were gps provider just stopped
}
```

Comment: My logic is if there is a change in status of location provider then check whether both of GPS and network providers are stopped. If they are stopped do a task. If one or none is stopped, do else-task, Thus, I cannot think any solution does not use BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: However, BroadcastReceiver toggles "GPS <-> GPS + network" and "network <-> GPS + network" changes as well. I want to avoid this in a way. I will take a look at Otto library, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I realize this may not be the "quick fix" you may be looking for, but in the long run it simplifies things greatly.

Comment: I am aware of that this library provides extensive enhancement but I also cannot find wanting in my approach. Is there an overt drawback?

Comment: For one thing, your activity and receiver are very tightly coupled.  You are directly referring to  fields in your activity in the receiver. If you change the name of  your originButton, you will have change your receiver. You have code that updates your UI that the activity has no knowledge of.

Comment: I accept that this issue is incibus. Nevertheless, instead of code organization, I worry about the functioning of the system. If Otto library offers a better alternative in this respect, I will try to implement it asap.